# RadListView loadOnDemandMode indicator background color

Tags: nativescript

When using RadListView with `loadOnDemandMode="auto"`, how do I change the background color of the activity indicator in iOS?
In Android platform it seems to be the same as the background color, but in iOS it's white

Comment: Do you have a background color set to each row?

Comment: Is there some global property for rows background? I have a background color for the item container layout below the `ng-template`, nothing more

Comment: Try `listView.ios.loadOnDemandView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;`

Comment: I got: `ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.myListView.nativeElement.ios.loadOnDemandView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor'`, so I `console.log(this.myListView.nativeElement.ios)` and got: `<TKListView: 0x7f840ef8ade0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002342120>>`, but when I `console.log(this.myListView.nativeElement.ios.loadOnDemandView)`, I got `null`- does this line work only when I have a custom view?

Comment: May be you are accessing it too early, can you build a Playground sample of same?

Comment: I tried a `setTimeout()` of 5 seconds after the `ngOnInit()` - will build a playground sample and share here

Comment: That obviously won't work, you have to wait for the load demand view tempalte to be ready. So if you have a Playground, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

`collectionView.visibleCells` returns `ExtendedLoadOnDemandCell` as its first element which contains the activityindicator used in loadOnDemand mode.

Below is the code to set the activity indicator's color and backgroundColor to transparent

```js
this.listview.nativeView.collectionView.visibleCells[0].activityIndicator.color = UIColor.clearColor;
this.listview.nativeView.collectionView.visibleCells[0].activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
```

Set this on the `tkListLoadOnDemandTemplate`'s loaded event. You might also have to wrap it in a `setTimeout` incase it fires too early.

```html
<GridLayout *tkListLoadOnDemandTemplate (loaded)="onLoadOnDemandLoaded($event)"></GridLayout>
```

```js
onLoadOnDemandLoaded(args) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.listview.nativeView.collectionView.visibleCells[0].activityIndicator.color = UIColor.clearColor;
    this.listview.nativeView.collectionView.visibleCells[0].activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
  });
}
```